# WCF Ajax Call not working with Jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, json, post

I have the following jQuery (service name altered):

```
var url = "http://localhost/services/MyService.svc/addentrant";
var stuff = $("#signup-form").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: stuff,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (obj) { alert('yay!'); }
});
```

The above makes a request to a WCF service hosted in Sitefinity on my local IIS7.5 server. Below is the relevant web.config:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="jsonBehavior">
  <webHttp/>
</behavior>
...
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
...
<services>
 <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="Services.MyService" >
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Services.IMyService" bindingConfiguration=""/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
 </service>
...
```

Finally, the interface and implementation of MyService:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "MyService", Namespace = "http://myservice.com/services/2010/")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract,
    WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
              UriTemplate = "addentrant")]
    void AddEntrant(string firstName);
}
...
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService : IMyervice
{
...
    public void AddEntrant(string firstName)
    {
        Entrant entrant = new Entrant()
        {
            FirstName = firstName,
        };
        context.Entrants.InsertOnSubmit(entrant);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I think that's everything. Anyway, the $.ajax call returns a success, but the web service method was not being called (I had a breakpoint set). **I opened up Fiddler and found I was being given a 405: Method Not Allowed**. I've seen that before, but only when I had forgotten to set up the method to allow POST requests. I'm very confused as to why it is doing this now.

Also, oddly enough, if I clone the ajax request captured in Fiddler, I get the following:

```
OPTIONS /services/MyService.svc/addentrant HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:6339
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

Just the header, no request body to speak of.

Comment: One other question -- what does `stuff` look like?  Does it serialize to `firstName: "name"` (pseudo-code)?

Comment: It's a jQuery serialized array object, like [Object { name="firstName", value="Bob" }, {name="lastName", value="Bob"}...].

Comment: I'm not sure how, in your service, a string of firstName can map to what you're sending up (a serialized JavaScript object literal).  Is this just pseudo-code?  Also, with the ajax request capture that you pasted, where are you copying that data from?  If you click on the 'TextView' tab in the Request pane (on the top right-hand side), do you not see your payload?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your Fiddler request, the HTTP verb that you're using is OPTIONS, not POST.  That's why you're getting the 405 back.  If I take a POST request that only allows POST and try to do a GET, I get a 405 in Fiddler (and in my app).  So I guess I'm wondering is there anything else running on your machine (proxy?) that would cause this?  Is your client and server on the same domain (same server, same port -- e.g., localhost:53128)?

Comment: The web service is hosted on localhost (in IIS7.5). The site making the $.ajax request is hosted on localhost:24526 (some random port, in the app dev server). I noticed that Fiddler keeps cloning the request using the OPTIONS verb; no idea why it is doing that. It almost seems like the request header sent from $.ajax *is* OPTIONS, but that doesn't make any sense. I do not actually see the payload in Fiddler :(.

Comment: In Fiddler's Request Builder, can you change the verb from OPTIONS to POST?  It should be a drop-down and you should be able to change it.  You'll probably have to manually enter your payload in the Request Body area in the bottom right pane.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: It works when I do that! Awesome. Turns out the OPTIONS request problem is a symptom of cross-domain policy issues in FireFox. I've moved the site to a subfolder of the same domain as the service now (which is where it will live in production anyway), so they're on the same domain. The OPTIONS method problem has gone away. Now just trying to format the JSON so the service will accept it proper...

Comment: That's great.  I should have noticed that sooner.  Also, you may want to set the `RequestFormat` in your `[WebInvoke]` to `WebMessageFormat.Json`.  I don't think I've used the `BodyStyle` parameter for handling JSON data.

Comment: Let me know if you're problem is solved -- I'm curious now.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll post the full fix as soon as this thing wraps up.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to use GET instead of POST?

Try clearing your cache or appending a timestamp to the url - the 200 response code may have been cached by the browser

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a $.get; wish I could get by just using that, but this is a contest entry form :/. Going to try appending a timestamp.

Comment: No change when I added a timestamp to the end. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is not setting the `contentType` in your `$.ajax` call and use `dataType: "json"` instead.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: stuff,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (obj) { alert('yay!'); }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, no change in behavior.