# jQuery Ajax POST unsuccessful

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm unable to successfully post using jquery's ajax functionality.

URL of the running page is `http://localhost:9999`, URL of the target (web service) is `http://localhost:8080`. No the ports aren't the same, they are 9999 and 8080 respectively.

Below is the request and jquery ajax code.

**Request:**

```
OPTIONS /profile/set_member HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:9999
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

**jQuery ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", url: "http://localhost:8080/profile/set_member", 
        contentType: "application/json", data: member, 
        error: function(){ alert('Update failed!'); }, 
        processData: false, 
        success: function(){ alert('Update successful!'); }
});
```

Comment: Are you posting from the same domain?

Comment: What's the URL of the running page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with cross-domain ajax calls. Basically (at least in Firefox), a POST request is converted to an OPTIONS request for security reasons. I ran into the same *exact* thing last night, posted here.

[WCF Ajax Call not working with Jquery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578614/wcf-ajax-call-not-working-with-jquery-ajax)

I had an $.ajax call I was making on localhost:23485, to a web service on http://localhost hosted in IIS. Because they are different domains, cross-domain kicked in and made things difficult.

Comment: A more irritating symptom is that the $.ajax call will often report success when it makes this particular kind of call, even though it didn't actually work.

Comment: Also, looking at your request header, I see that the Origin and Host addresses are both localhost, but from different ports. Exactly the same thing I ran into last night :(.

Comment: @Dusda: You're right it's the same problem. Seemingly the 'only' solution is to have a proxy between the ajax call and the web service.

Comment: @Mads610, not necessarily.  You can take advantage of the JSONP spec: http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding.  I've made this work a number of times before.

Comment: Chris is correct; you can leverage jsonp for cross domain calls. Just requires a bit more work.

Comment: Yes, especially if you have access to the code on the other server.

Answer (score 4):

Make a proxy on the same domain you are calling the ajax, e.g. in PHP:

```
<?php /* get.php */
    $url = $_GET["Url"];
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Make your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ url: "get.php?Url=realurl.com" });
```

That's one workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What handler gets called? The `success` or `error` handler? Can you elaborate what "doesn't work" means?

You probably want `alert` more information in your `error` handler, like so:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   //console.log is better at least for debugging. You can change this back to alert 
   //when your code goes into production
   console.log("Update unsuccessful. Status: ", textStatus, " error thrown: ", errorThrown);
}
```

`textStatus` should give you an idea as to what the problem could be. Possible values are "timeout", "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror". Once you figure out the actual error, please update the question.

Also if you have Firebug check the Net tab to see the request and the response. A few common sources of errors:

- Violating same-origin policy. You cannot make an AJAX to a different URL from the parent page.
- Server-side errors. If your server returns something like a 500 response code, the request will fail.
- Parsing errors. If you're expecting a specific response format like `json` or `xml`, and if the response is not in that format, the AJAX request will be unsuccessful.