# jQuery post respond with readyState:0, status:0

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

all. I am using a jquery version 1.6.2.
I do a ajax call like this:

```
  var jqxhr = $j.post(myPHP, function() {
          alert("success");
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

The script, run, and show error, than, complete. Some people may thing that...myPHP have some problem, but the myPHP is always show:

```
{"sayHi":"hihi"}
```

So, I go to firebugs to check whether the link have any problem, when I called..:
It show me the POST url with status 200, which is ok. Also, I can see the respond via firebugs....
But the question is ....why the jquery so me have a error...:
And here is the error msg:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: Solved, I know wt happen:
cross-domain ajax calls....
Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586780/jquery-ajax-post-unsuccessful

Comment: It is about cross-site scripting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586780/jquery-ajax-post-unsuccessful

Answer (score 3):

For me this problem was caused by a cross-domain issue.
So I had a local html file (`c:\test.html`) and tried to get data from a server (localhost/servlet).
When putting html on the server - the problem was gone.

Answer (score 3):

If the browser switches the web page while an XHR request is still in progress (the user clicked a link, the back button, …), this XHR request will be cancelled with exactly your error.

Have a look at the following blog post, where the issue is explained in depth: http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2012/02/ajax-request-returns-status-0.html

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell jQuery that the server is returning JSON:

```
   var jqxhr = $j.post(myPHP, function() {
           alert("success");
         }, "json") // here
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: still error, btw, if the return is plain text, do I need to mention?

Comment: Are you doing `json_encode()` on the server? No, you don't need to mention "text".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not due to Cross domain. I was not using e.PreventDefault(). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395354/jquery-ajax-readystate-0-responsetext-status-0-statustext-error/#22238895)