# JavaScript REST retrieve elements

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a result from Fiddler (please see the attached image), how can I get the results where the arrow is pointing to?
This is what I have done so far and thank you:

[image: arrow]

```
function GetRefiners() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "myUrl",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.d.query, function(list){
        });
   },
       error: function(error){
           alert("Error message\n" + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    }
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to the results objects and iterates over it

```
function GetRefiners() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "myUrl",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RefinementResults.Refiners.results.Entries.results, function(list){
                callWhatYouNeed();
           }
        };
   },
       error: function(error){
           alert("Error message\n" + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you I tried but the error function is called (I get error)

Comment: Please read your question... Is it clear for you ? Did you say that there is an error or did you ask to get the results ?

Comment: If the error function is called it is due to your ajax call. Please provide the error

Comment: The error is: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: As I said this is an error linked to your ajax... Your question was very badly explained
Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395354/jquery-ajax-readystate-0-responsetext-status-0-statustext-error

Comment: My question was how to get the results.  Then I tried your solution and I get the error.  What we are talking about?

Comment: Just call your ajax without anything inside success. Are your sure that your ajax call is working ?

Comment: if you mean the url request, yes... I used in Fiddelr to get the result.  I called the with empty success and still get error.

Comment: debug and see if it gets inside the success function

Comment: Then its not a problem about what I wrote but about the AJAX call

Comment: Ok it's solved, seems like doesn't like localhost, I need to specify the host name.  Thank you! :-)

Comment: No problem ! Have fun