# Cant receive Json response from Api using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner in Javasript.Now I trying to make a `http` request to my php server,which will return a Json response like this:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "username": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "http://192.168.1.1/abc/v1/profilepic/defaultmale.jpg"
  }
}
```

I make the Ajax call like the following,but I didn't get any response from my browser,and as I see is didn't do anything.

**What I tried so far**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loginBtn").click(function () {

            var vEmail = $("#email").val();
            var vPassword = $("#password").val();

            if(vEmail ==='' &&vPassword === ''){
                alert("please enter email and password");
            }else if(vEmail !== '' && vPassword===''){
                alert("password required");
            }else if(vEmail ==='' && vPassword !== ''){
                alert("email required");
            }else{

                $.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",
                    {email:vEmail, password:vPassword},
                    function(response){ // Required Callback Function
                        //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                        alert(response);
                    }
                );


            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I cant get `alert` in my browser,I tried `console.log(response)` as well,I also cant see in my `inspect element` in Google Chrome.

I tried like below as well,also no luck

```
var obj = $.parseJson(response);
alert(obj['user_id']);
```

**What I need to know**

1) Is this the correct way to make the Http request via Jquery?If not,what is the correct way?

2) How can I test whether I successfully get the response?can it be print out anyway for testing purpose?

3) How can I parse the Json correctly using Jquery?

Thanks for advance.

**UPDATE**
I adding the fail function as well,but when I filled in `email` and `password`,it still nothing happen(means the browser just refresh,no alert,console log just blank).

```
$.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",
                {email:vEmail, password:vPassword},
                function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
                    //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));

                },fail(function () {
                    alert("failed");
                })
            );
```

Can somebody show me the correct way to do it?

**UPDATE**

After following @Mendax answer,I get the response in console.log with this response.What is this means?

**Error**

```
Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Comment: F12 development mode, check console errors. I think there is a cross-domain issue.

Comment: Add `fail` function so that you can catch erros.

Comment: I checked console,is just blank,no any single word on it

Comment: yes i think you got error and you have not written fail function. please check with fail function

Comment: test your api with a rest client

Comment: you have to pass data type 'json' in the post method to receive output in json  format. Please check my answer that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending data as `JSON` string. Also add a `fail` callback to catch erros

```
    $.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",
        JSON.stringify({email:vEmail, password:vPassword}),
        function(response){ // Required Callback Function
            //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
            console.log(response);
        }, "json").fail(function(error) { console.log(error) });;
```

2. To test if you get the response you can visit `newtwork` tab in your console or adding `fail` callback will help.
3. to parse a `JSON`  you can use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Sir,your code have response,but the alert is `undefined`.What is the cause ya??

Comment: nice,at least I get some response with this.I update my question,cause I dont know what it means for the response

Comment: @ken I saw your update, But you are not passing `error` to alert.. try printing tha `fail` function parameter to get an insight about the issue

Comment: @ken also you didn't try stringifying the data you sent, like in my answer

Comment: Ok..what I make a change now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143066/discussion-between-mendax-and-ken).

Comment: Sir I do the `JSON.stringify` just like your answer,but the http call is just failed.with this `response`

Comment: `Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Comment: it must be a cross domain issue then.. :(  

try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586780/jquery-ajax-post-unsuccessful

Comment: @ken did you try adding data-type? `"json"`. Since your response from server is a `JSON` you need to add that too I guess..

Comment: I added the `JSON` as data type,but it still produce out the `error`.I will tried to solve the cross domain issue.

Comment: ,sir just wanna ask,my web project and the webservice project is in the same localhost,is it the cross domain issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method to send request and Get response in jquery.
Here form is Form method where your input controls live and email/passwords are the text box id.
Also make sure the Url you are using is response when passing parameters.

```
 $.post( "http://localhost/abc/v1/login", {email:form.email.value, 
  password:form.password.value })
 .done(function( data ) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
 });
```

Comment: sir I test in postman,my api is working,but I use ur code,and submit it,it still no response in browser

Answer (score 0):

Pass `json` parameter in [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) if it your response is in `JSON` format like,

```
$.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",{email:vEmail, password:vPassword}, function(response){ // Required Callback Function
    //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
    alert(response);
},'json');// pass json parameter here
```

Also, check in your browser's console and make sure that your AJAX request is made correctly, and there is no errors from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `data type` in the $.post method like:

```
               $.post("http://localhost/abc/v1/login",
                    {email:vEmail, password:vPassword},
                    function(response){ // Required Callback Function
                        //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                        alert(response);
                    },'json'// Data type to output json format
                );
```

This will work